# How paginated DynamoDB query behave when the date change between pages?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pagination, amazon-dynamodb

I am doing a paginated query to DynamoDB using DynamoDBMapper. The query is based on some Local Secondary Index (the `index` field), that combines information if an entry is marked as deleted with timestamp. Say I have the following data:

```
{..., creationTime: 1000, isDeleted: false, index=F:1000}
{..., creationTime: 1001, isDeleted: false, index=F:1001}
{..., creationTime: 1002, isDeleted: false, index=F:1002}
{..., creationTime: 1003, isDeleted: false, index=F:1003}
```

Now I do the query and on the first page of results and get the two entries:

```
{..., creationTime: 1000, isDeleted: false, index=F:1000}
{..., creationTime: 1001, isDeleted: false, index=F:1001}
```

I query for the second page and I should get the remaining two entries:

```
{..., creationTime: 1002, isDeleted: false, index=F:1002}
{..., creationTime: 1003, isDeleted: false, index=F:1003}
```

But what if between the pages the third entry is marked as deleted?

```
{..., creationTime: 1002, isDeleted: true, index=D:1002} << changed !
```

Will the second page of the results deliver

- single element (fourth one, with creationTime=1003),
- both elements up-to date (i.e, the element with the index that wouldn't qualify it to be returned in the results),
- both elements, but the third one not up-to date (unlikely)?

Related:

- [DynamoDB: Query And Scan - Pagination](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#Pagination)
- [DynamoDB: Secondary Indexes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html)

Comment: its depend on your index. can you describe your Local Secondary Index?

Comment: edited. `index` field is used as range key

Answer (score 2):

dynamodb order the results by the range key.
in your case, the range key (index) is string, so the order will be by its string value.

when you request for a page, you need to provide the last evaluated key (the last range key then returned from the previous page)

by this 'last evaluated key', dynamodb know which page to return.

*so lets take your example*

your range key is in format of 'F/D:'

string value of 'F' is always bigger then 'D'

so i any 'F' record will change to 'D' then it will never return in next page (if you arrived to a page with index that is starting with 'F') (unless change the ordering (ASC/DESC) but this is not your case).

so lets assume index looks like that:

```
{..., creationTime: 1000, isDeleted: false, index=D:1000}
{..., creationTime: 1000, isDeleted: false, index=F:1000}
{..., creationTime: 1001, isDeleted: false, index=F:1001}
{..., creationTime: 1002, isDeleted: false, index=F:1002}
{..., creationTime: 1002, isDeleted: false, index=F:1003}
```

if your first page is:

```
{..., creationTime: 1000, isDeleted: false, index=D:1000}
{..., creationTime: 1000, isDeleted: false, index=F:1000}
{..., creationTime: 1001, isDeleted: false, index=F:1001}
```

and

```
{..., creationTime: 1002, isDeleted: false, index=F:1002}
```

changed to deleted then your next page will be:

```
{..., creationTime: 1002, isDeleted: false, index=F:1003}
```

because now your index looks like that:

```
{..., creationTime: 1000, isDeleted: false, index=D:1000}
{..., creationTime: 1002, isDeleted: true, index=D:1002}
{..., creationTime: 1000, isDeleted: false, index=F:1000}
{..., creationTime: 1001, isDeleted: false, index=F:1001}
{..., creationTime: 1002, isDeleted: false, index=F:1003}
```